# How does the equation of a plane magically decide the positive normal direction of the plane when there are two directions?

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

Sorry if this is a basic question.

I have just started to realize this.

To find the normal of a plane we just take the cross product of any two vectors lying in the plane. However, depending on the order of the vectors in the cross product, we get two different vectors (opposite to each other) that are both normal to the plane.

Yet, when I also know that for a plane $ax+by+cz=d$, the normal vector is $(a,b,c)$.

What is so special about the equation of a plane that can identify/define the positive direction for the normal when a cross product of two vectors in the plane cannot?

I was thinking about the right-hand rule when doing the cross product but when a plane is arbitrary, which side do I view it from?

Thank you.

Comment: The normal to a plne is, in fact, not a real vector but a PSEUDOVECTOR, which, roughly speaking, means a vector for which the SENSE doesn't matter. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector )

Comment: The plane ax+by+cz=d is the same plane as -ax-by-cz=-d, which tells you that (-a,-b,-c) is also normal to the plane. There are still two!

Comment: @Peter In fact, there are infinitely many: Just multiply your equation $ax+by+cz=d$ by any nonzero scalar $m\ne0$: $max+may+maz=md$ and you'll get $(ma,mb,mc)$ is still normal (which is obvious).

Comment: @TitoEliatron, True. Also the cross product of pu and qv has infinitely many values. Perhaps the answer to "what's so special" is "nothing".

Comment: @TitoEliatron (a,b,c) are direction ratios so $(ma,mb,mc)$ is not  any unique